# Switching 2003 SRV to 2008 caused Asp.net application not to Import Dll

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

Switching aged 2003 SRV to 2008 caused my  Asp.net 2 application fail: The application is no more loading the required library DLL from /bin/ folder anymore.

What should I change in my code or web.config to make this webapp load OK also in new 2008 server?

Now I receive this error when I access the application:  This type is in IMPORTS  ( Dll ).

> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type
>   'Facebook.Entity.User' is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing some of the required libraries.  Make sure Facebook.Controls.dll, Facebook.dll, and Facebook.WebControls.dll are in the bin folder AND accessible (check security) by the app pool identity.

Next, check the application pool pipeline settings.  Is it set to integrated v2.0?  Does the identity of the app pool have the right access to that folder?

Also, did you change from an x86 to an x64 server?  If so, you might redeploy the app to specifically target x86.